# the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'generator'

Tags: python, django

I have made a program of scraping data from two url :
{ 
    "url" : "https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168#.XaA9cEZKiUk" ,
    "svgurl":"https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/themes/amcharts4/css/img/icons/weather/animated/cloudy.svg"
}
the first one just information text and the seconde one to store the svg data so i want to execute two function in the same time without using thread using instead asyncio

My Goal is to transform synchronous python code to Asynchronous code this is what i have made for that :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import json
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import JsonResponse 
from django.core.serializers import serialize 
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import base64 

from cairosvg import svg2png
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
# Create your views here.
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio

@api_view(["POST"])
def Post(request):
    global srcsnapcodeimg,soup,tonight,sourcesvg

    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    url = body['url']
    urlsvg=body['svgurl']
    source = requests.get(url).text
    sourcesvg=requests.get(urlsvg).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    seven_day = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast")
    forecast_items = seven_day.find_all(class_="tombstone-container")
    tonight = forecast_items[0]


    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(Getvalues()),
        asyncio.ensure_future(Get_bin_img())]

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    print(Get_bin_img())
    Getvalues_dict = json.loads(asyncio.wait(Getvalues()))
    data={"period":Getvalues_dict['period'] ,"short_desc":Getvalues_dict['short_desc'],"temp":Getvalues_dict['temp']}
    #print(data)
    return JsonResponse(data)    

@asyncio.coroutine
def Getvalues():
    period = tonight.find(class_="period-name").get_text()
    short_desc = tonight.find(class_="short-desc").get_text()
    temp = tonight.find(class_="temp").get_text()
    datanameboxandprice={"period":period,"short_desc":short_desc,"temp":temp}
    return  json.dumps(datanameboxandprice)

@asyncio.coroutine
def Get_bin_img():
    svg2png(bytestring=sourcesvg,write_to='output.png')
    with open("output.png", "rb") as imageFile:
        base64code = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    return base64code
```

i have this error in my postman : when i send post request :

the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'generator'

the synchronous code is working fine :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import json
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import JsonResponse 
from django.core.serializers import serialize 
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import base64 

from cairosvg import svg2png
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
# Create your views here.
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup


@api_view(["POST"])
def Post(request):
    global srcsnapcodeimg,soup,tonight,sourcesvg

    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    url = body['url']
    urlsvg=body['svgurl']
    source = requests.get(url).text
    sourcesvg=requests.get(urlsvg).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    seven_day = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast")
    forecast_items = seven_day.find_all(class_="tombstone-container")
    tonight = forecast_items[0]
    print(Get_bin_img())
    Getvalues_dict = json.loads(Getvalues())

    data={"period":Getvalues_dict['period'] ,"short_desc":Getvalues_dict['short_desc'],"temp":Getvalues_dict['temp']}
    #print(data)
    return JsonResponse(data)    


def Getvalues():
    period = tonight.find(class_="period-name").get_text()
    short_desc = tonight.find(class_="short-desc").get_text()
    temp = tonight.find(class_="temp").get_text()
    #PrevClosevalue=soup.find('div',class_='value__b93f12ea').text.strip()
    datanameboxandprice={"period":period,"short_desc":short_desc,"temp":temp}
    return  json.dumps(datanameboxandprice)


def Get_bin_img():
    svg2png(bytestring=sourcesvg,write_to='output.png')
    with open("output.png", "rb") as imageFile:
        base64code = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    return base64code
```

Comment: can you ```print(type(Getvalues())``` It should be String, but the only reason it would throw this error is if it is a "generator" object and not a String.

Comment: the synchronous code is working fine i have only the problem in asynch code can you help me to fix it

Comment: Can you please tell me the output of the following:
```print(type(datanameboxandprice))``` 

Why do a json.dumps and then a loads. Why not return the json directly and try?

Comment: in the asynch code i have the same error the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'generator' when i make print(type(datanameboxandprice))  when i made it for synchronious code that works fine i have <class 'dict'>

Comment: and print(type(Getvalues()) i have <class 'str'> as the result